# How do I keep the drive letter unchanged when inserting or removing a hard disk on a server running ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, disk

For example, slot 5 of the server contains hard disk A whose drive letter is /dev/sda. If hard disk A is damaged and hard disk B is replaced, the drive letter of hard disk B is still /dev/sda

Answer (score 2):

The disk names such as `sda` are assigned in order as the kernel finds them. If your removable disk isn't present at boot time other disks will be assigned first.

Consider using `/dev/disk/by-path` for physical location, or `/dev/disk/by-uuid` or `/dev/disk-by-label` for per-disk identifiers.

Examples

```
# Only if you know for sure sda is the right disk
mount /dev/sda /mnt/dsk

# This physical slot
mount /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1.0-part4 /mnt/dsk

# Assumes label "my_usb_disk"
mount /dev/disk/by-label/my_usb_disk /mnt/dsk

# Assumes UUID
mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/7dd4219a-60c8-40db-a4ff-fe62ce474c47 /mnt/dsk
```

If you know that `sda` is currently the correct disk you can identify which of the `disk/by-*` devices refers to it as they are all symbolic links.

In my case,

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1.0-part4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 11 10:26 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1.0-part4 -> ../../sda4
```